# Drawing a tilemap using python and pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am creating a tile-map in `python` using `pygame`. The code I have (see below) works OK, but I was wandering if there were any improvements.

This code creates a tilemap and scrolls it horizontally:

```py
from enum import Enum

import pygame
pygame.init()

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 500

TILE_SIZE = 50


class TileTypes(Enum):
    AIR = 0
    GRASS = 1
    ROCK = 2
    LAVA = 3


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

screen.fill((255,) * 3)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

MAP_WIDTH = SCREEN_WIDTH // TILE_SIZE
MAP_HEIGHT = SCREEN_HEIGHT // TILE_SIZE

map_layout = [[TileTypes.AIR for j in range(MAP_WIDTH)]
              for i in range(MAP_HEIGHT)]


def draw_map():
    y = 0
    for row in map_layout:
        x = 0
        for tile in row:
            match tile:
                case TileTypes.AIR:
                    pass

                case TileTypes.GRASS:
                    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), (x, y, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE))

                case TileTypes.ROCK:
                    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (150, 150, 150), (x, y, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE))

            x += TILE_SIZE

        y += TILE_SIZE


def scroll_map():
    for row in map_layout:
        row.append(row.pop(0))

map_layout[-2] = map_layout[-1] = [TileTypes.ROCK for i in range(MAP_WIDTH)]
map_layout[-3] = [TileTypes.GRASS for i in range(MAP_WIDTH)]
map_layout[-4][2:4] = map_layout[-4][6:8] = [TileTypes.GRASS for i in range(2)]


done = False


while not done:
    if any(event.type == pygame.QUIT for event in pygame.event.get()):
        done = True

    scroll_map()

    screen.fill((255,) * 3)
    draw_map()

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(20)

pygame.quit()
```

[image: tilemap]

I would be grateful for any improvements.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ thank you for pointing this out to me. I have now fixed the code so that the tilemap scrolls horizontally and made the question about general, not specific improvements, is it on topic now?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it appears to be on-topic and I have re-opened it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like this code.
It accomplishes a simple goal in a simple way, very direct and clear.

Conforming to pep8 and using Enum is very nice.

It reminds me of POKE -16298, 0 for LORES graphic mode.

Let's examine low level details first.

---

## `__main__` guard

```
pygame.init()
...
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
screen.fill((255,) * 3)
```

I'm not crazy about doing a bunch of stuff at top level.
Prefer to protect such statements with a main guard.
The standard idiom is:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
```

Why do we do this?
Well, I understand that no file has an `import scrolling_game`
statement, **yet**.
But we anticipate that could happen in future.
For example if you write a
[unit test](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase)
or use a couple of modules to implement a fancier game.

The idea is that another file should be able to import
this one with no side effects, e.g. `print()` statements
or game windows opening.
So class / function definitions are fair game,
plus constants like width / height.
But the meat of the application typically goes into
`def main():` which we run according to what
the module `__name__` is.
Notice that, for someone importing this module,
the module name will look like `"scrolling_game"`
rather than `"__main__"`.

That third statement, which blanks out the screen with white,
appears to be leftover from initial development / debug,
and should just be deleted.
Once the main display loop begins it becomes superfluous.

And defining a WHITE
[manifest constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))
wouldn't hurt.

---

## cells dictate the display

```
def draw_map():
            ...
            match tile:
                case TileTypes.AIR:
                    pass
```

```
while not done:
    ...
    screen.fill((255,) * 3)  # <-- recommend you delete this
    draw_map()
```

I'm not keen on the `pass`, there.
Prefer to repaint every tile, every time,
rather than defaulting all tiles to AIR
followed by selective repaint of non-AIR tiles.
The current code makes sense, but I will
introduce an alternate repainting strategy below.

Also, the `match` works out fine.
But it would be better to put a color attribute
on each Enum value, so we could unconditionally
do lookup + render.

---

## use an array

```
map_layout = [[TileTypes.AIR for j in range(MAP_WIDTH)]
              for i in range(MAP_HEIGHT)]
```

In Lisp and in Python a list-of-lists datastructure
can be a very nice representation of N items
that are "all the same thing", like tiles.
But it suffers from chasing N object pointers,
which aren't cache friendly.
CPU hardware is good at predicting and prefetching
sequential reads, but less so for random reads.

Prefer to represent N tiles with a vector, perhaps an
[array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) or an
[ndarray](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.html).
That leaves us with something like

```
map_layout = np.ones((MAP_WIDTH, MAP_HEIGHT)) * TileTypes.AIR
```

---

## slice when scrolling

A central concern is how to efficiently move the grid by
one tile in any direction.

Let's start with a level that spans several screens:

```
level = np.ones((5 * MAP_WIDTH, 3 * MAP_HEIGHT)) * TileTypes.AIR
```

Pure AIR would be boring, so fill in additional level tiles to taste.

Now let's render a portion of that level:

```
x, y = get_current_position()
map_layout = level[x : x+MAP_WIDTH][y : y+MAP_HEIGHT]
```

We can advance `x` or `y` by +/- 1 pixel
and re-render to scroll to a new spot within the level.
Rather than interpreted bytecode we are looping in C,
so it's essentially MAP_HEIGHT memcpy()'s per screen refresh,
with no random reads from chasing object pointers.

If all levels have similar dimensions, then you could
move from two dimensions to a three-dimensional array:
`level[lvl][x][y]`

---

This is solid code.
I would be happy to delegate or accept maintenance tasks for it.

Recommend the use of array slicing for frame updates.

Comment: `np.ones((MAP_WIDTH, MAP_HEIGHT)) * TileTypes.AIR` results in an error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'TileTypes`. Wouldn't something like `np.full()` work better?

Comment: Agreed. Though we'll still want AIR (or AIR.value) to give us a small integer, even if used as fill_value for .full(). Plus AIR.color should give us an RGB white value, GRASS.color should give a green triple, and so on, which is easily arranged, so no need for a separate enum_to_color dict.